# Learning OOP in PHP, trying to refactor my code. Can't connect to database anymore

Tags: php, oop, class, pdo

Thought I understood how classes work, then I tried this code:

```
class user
  {
  var $dbcon;

  var $dbinfo;
  var $con;    
  var $error;

  function dbConnect()
    {

    $this->dbinfo['server'] = "localhost";
    $this->dbinfo['database'] = "foolish_faith";
    $this->dbinfo['user'] = "user";
    $this->dbinfo['password'] = "password";

    $this->con = "mysql:host=".$dbinfo['server']."; dbname=".$dbinfo['database'];
    $this->dbcon = new PDO($con, $dbinfo['user'], $dbinfo['password']);
    $this->dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->error = $this->dbcon->errorInfo();

    if ($error[0] != "")
      {
      print "Error!";
      print_r($error);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now it just spits out this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'invalid
>   data source name' in
>   E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\dbcon.php:24
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\dbcon.php(24):
>   PDO->__construct('', NULL, NULL) #1
>   E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\login.php(4):
>   user->dbConnect() #2 {main} thrown in
>   E:\PortableApps\xampp\htdocs\dbcon.php
>   on line 24

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong, as I'm sure it has to do with my lack of knowledge when it comes to classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->con = "mysql:host=".$dbinfo['server']."; dbname=".$dbinfo['database'];
$this->dbcon = new PDO($con, $dbinfo['user'], $dbinfo['password']);
```

When you acces variables of a class instance you have to use the -> operator. In this case you'd use `$this->dbinfo` instead of just `$dbinfo` and `$this->con` instead of `$con`. You've done it correctly on the left side, but missed some on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put spaces in your connection string. (`"; dbname="` should be `";dbname="`).

Also, there are a couple of instances where you need to add a `$this->` in front of some class instance variables (`$this->con`, `$this->dbinfo` et cetera).

Answer (score 1):

Make this: `$this->dbcon = new PDO($con, $dbinfo['user'], $dbinfo['password']);`
Int this: `$this->dbcon = new PDO($this->con, $dbinfo['user'], $dbinfo['password']);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dsn syntax : https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php
I don't see any space in it, maybe you should remove the one you added after the semicolon...